# Vue Router - Populate details view with json from home view

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue app I have a home view looping through posts from an api

```
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/
```

Using Axios is my `index.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  fetchPosts () {
    return axios
      .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
      .then(response => response.data)
  }
}
```

My Home view post setup with a router-link generating a details view from the json post id

```
   <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.title" class="post-item">
   <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'details', params: { id: post.id }}"> {{ post.title }}</router-link>
   </li>
```

My Home script

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    posts () {
      return this.$store.state.posts
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.loading = true
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchPosts')
      .then(posts => {
        this.loading = false
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

The Router link correctly generates a details view based on the json id so post 1 generates a page called `/details/1` as my current router is set up

```
  const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: '/details/:id',
      name: 'details',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "details" */ './views/Details.vue'),
      props: true
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

Inside my details view `/views/Details.vue` I have

```
<template>
<p> The post id is: {{ $route.params.id }} </p>
</template>
```

which correctly retrieves the json from my home view `The detail is: 1`

How do I get the post title , body etc into the details view from the home view?

Please let me know if I need to provide any other code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using `axios` or some `ajax` to fetch data, if so, try doing this:

```
data() {
  return {
    myPost: {}
  }
}
mounted() {
  const base = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  axios.get(`${base}/posts/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
    this.myPost = resp.data;
  });
}
```

If you don't want to do another `axios` call and use the data this already fetched then pass full detail object in param like this `params: { post: post }`, check this code:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'details', params: { id: post.id, post: post }}"> {{ post.title }}</router-link>
```

then get the data in this way `$route.params.post.YOUR-KEY`:

```
<template>
  <p> The post id is: {{ $route.params.post.id }} </p>
  <p> The post title is: {{ $route.params.post.title }} </p>
</template>
```

Comment: I am using axios in in my index.js ```export default {
  fetchPosts () {
    return axios
      .get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
      .then(response => response.data)
  }
}``` , Would this go in the same index.js or in my details view?

Comment: @Mills I have updated the answer, can you pls check.

Comment: I updated my router link in home to your updated answer, along with the details template, I am getting a `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"` I also updated my question to include my home script, thanks for your help.

Comment: `vue-router] missing param for named route "details": Expected "id" to be defined`

Comment: try: params: `{ id: post.id, post: post }}`, if this dons't work, ping me on skype `syed_haroon`, let have a skype call.

Comment: `{ id: post.id, post: post }}` worked with the route params, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping the `<router-link>` directly like this

```
<router-link v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="post-item" tag="li" :to="{name:'details',params:{id:post.id}}">
  {{ post.title }}
</router-link>
```